# Does sunlight affect the power of a laser?

Tags: photons, laser

If I was to accurately aim a laser with 0 divergence at a target about 2 miles away, would the power received during day and night differ?

Comment: can you clarify why you suspect the power delivered by a laser might be affected by daylight?

Comment: My friend believes it will, and though I don't think he's correct, I don't have a proper explanation of why he's incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Light received from the laser would be the same. But if laser emitted red light, for example, the red light received from the sun may be much greater than that received from the laser. Depending of course on the power of the laser. So in daylight, it may be hard to tell if laser light is striking the target.

Comment: As a follow up question, would a laser which blinds (in the sense of cause physical eye damage) someone at night blind someone during the day?

Comment: Yes. The power from your laser that reaches the eye will be the same at night and at day.

Comment: @Sebastian During the day, the eye's  pupil is smaller. Chances are that less laser rays go through to affect the retina than at night